# ValueError : The given username must be set

Tags: python, html, django, null, set

``i am trying to do a register form in python django ,if we click on submit without providing username then this error shows( when username field have null value).i want to check if username is none or not before submit.

register.py

### Registration Form

```
<label><b>Username</b></label>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username" ><br>
  <label><b>Password</b></label>
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" ><br>


<label><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
<input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Confirm Your Password"><br>

        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:center;padding-top:25px;">

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

views.py

def register(request):

```
if request.method=='POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    cpassword = request.POST['password1']
    if password == cpassword:
        if  User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            messages.info(request, "Username already exist")
            return redirect('register')


        else:
            user=User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password)
            user.save();
            return redirect('login')
       

    else:
        messages.info(request,"password not matching")
        return redirect('register')
    return redirect('/')
return render(request,"")`
```

Comment: You could add a conditional statement before ```username = request.POST['username']``` that checks if the username is in the POST.

Comment: Just add `required` prop to username input element (I don't see it in shared snippet tho)

Comment: That form does not have a username input element...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i'll like to highlight the following issues with your already existing code snippet

1. Missing csrf token in the form - Django security middleware won't allow this url make a POST request
2. Relying on only backend validation - Although very important, you can save bandwidth if you do a pre-validation on the frontend by simply adding required attributes to the inputs and some JS to check for passwords match
3. No need to redirect the user to the register page - Just fill the form with some validation errors (if any) and return the filled form
4. The `create_user` method in the django `User` objects manager internally calls the `save` method, so no need to repeat that.

I have some snippet i'll suggest. Ofcourse it's so basic but should answer your question to the best of my knowledge

register.html

```
<form method="post">
  <ul>
  {% for error_message in form_error_messages %}
    <li style="color: red">{{error_message}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  <ul>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <b>Username</b>
  <input required type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="{{username}}" /><br />
  <br />
  <b>Password</b>
  <input required type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" /><br />
  <br />

  <label><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
  <input
    type="password"
    name="confirm_password"
    placeholder="Confirm Your Password"
  /><br />

  <div style="padding-top: 25px">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


def register(request):
    form_error_messages = []
    username = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        confirm_password = request.POST["confirm_password"]
        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            form_error_messages.append("User already exists!!")
        if password != confirm_password:
            form_error_messages.append("Passwords do not match!!")
        if not all([username, password, confirm_password]):
            form_error_messages.append("All fields are required!!")
        if not len(form_error_messages):
            User.objects.create_user(username=username,password=password)
            return redirect('login')

    return render(request, "my_auth/registration.html", {"form_error_messages": form_error_messages, "username": username})
```

**NOTE**:
Using model forms with the in built django `UserCreationForm` will go a long way reducing a lot of the bulk code written above and will do well with validation out of the box. This [article](https://www.pythontutorial.net/django-tutorial/django-registration/) will give you a good grasp on how you can do that